# navigation Drawer with listView and Expandable listview not scrolling

Tags: android, xml, navigation-drawer

I am building an app with a navigation drawer.

1. The navigation drawer has two listviews and an expandable listview.
2. I wish to scroll the navigation drawer as a whole.

my xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/drawer_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/navigation_header" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/popular_categories"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/popular_categories_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </ListView>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/all_categories"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ExpandableListView

            android:id="@+id/expandable_listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:childDivider="@color/white"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"
            android:indicatorEnd="285dp"
            android:indicatorStart="250dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/others"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/other_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

the listview itself do not scroll. and the underneath views stay hidden.

I wish to implement the drawer similar to the flipkart app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Design your layout as follows.
There is no need of multiple listviews and expandable listviews, You can handle it with single expandable listview.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".activity.HomeActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/actionbar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/commoncontainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"></RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@drawable/sidebar_bg"
        android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scrollbars="none"></ExpandableListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: but my app layout is as such that it demands  multiple list views

Comment: how will you manage too much scrollable items in single layout?

Comment: i am afraid i do not know.  But i wish to make it the way it is in flipkart app!

Comment: There is simple listview in flipkart app. Which can be easily implemented by this design

Comment: okay. thanks. i will remove the listviews. Can the header be scrolled too? for instance if i keep only a header and a listview inside the drawer and wish to scroll the header along with the listviews, as in gmail app, how can it be done?

Comment: it also can be done. Just add header to listview programatically